# Overriding another windows WindowProc in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm working on a personal project where I need to invoke my function after an menu item in another process is clicked.

I'm using

```
BOOL enumeratingWindowsSucceeded = ::EnumWindows(enumWindowsProc, NULL);
```

to retrieve the handles to all of the currently open windows on my computer and using

```
GetSystemMenu(...)
```

and

```
 AppendMenu(...)
```

to add an item into all the window's title bar context menu.

Now the problem is when the menu item is clicked in the other window's context menu, my program does not know about it.

Is there a way to override the WindowsProc of another window so that my process can execute some piece of code? Or is there a better way to make the menu item communicate with my program?

Thanks!

Comment: This can be done with a [hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx)

Comment: You cannot safely subclass another window's windowproc across process boundaries.  You have to use a message hook instead.